# Do dentures, denture cleaning tablets need to be Kosher for Passover?

Tags: halacha, passover, chametz-leaven, teeth

In the spirit of the Pre-Pesach holiday, I thought I might ask a question on Pesach Halachot...

I have a denture which has been cleaned with a standard denture cleaner. The cleaner is a tablet that is not specifically kosher for Passover. Can I keep the cleaners over Pesach, or do I need to sell them? Also, what is the status of the denture? Is it still Kosher to be used on Pesach?

Comment: My brother asked me this the other day. I told him I didn't know, and he just put it on his chametz-sale form anyway.

Comment: I edited your question's tags and title -- the title only reflected part of the question, and now it more completely represents your query. If my edits are not to your liking, feel free to [edit] back. Chag kasher v'sameach! :)

Comment: This is pure Pesak.  How is this open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this article](https://ohr.edu/5117).

I'm excerpting a few items that I think are most relevant: The question was initially asked by a young Rav SHlomo Zalman Aurbach zt"l:

> Relating to the issue of Bassar B’Chalav, dentures are deemed not to
>   be considered an actual utensil that requires kashering, but rather
>   similar to genuine teeth themselves, sharing the same relevant
>   halachos.
>
> Several authorities maintain that the very same ruling would apply for
>   Pesach, and rule that a thorough cleaning of the false teeth prior to
>   Pesach would be sufficient
>
> Yet, other authorities, including the famed Maharsham[4], feel that
>   one must be more stringent regarding Pesach, and rule that one must at
>   least do an Iruy Roschin, or pouring boiling hot water over them, to
>   be suitable for Pesach use. It must be noted, though, that Iruy is a
>   lesser form of kashering and is usually not considered an acceptable
>   process for utensils.
>
> Although he did qualify his resolution, stating that it is proper not
>   to eat any Chametz within 24 hours before Pesach, and to drink a hot
>   cup of water (hotter than usual) prior to the onset of Pesach, still,
>   he felt that even so, a proper oral cleaning would still be
>   halachically sufficient.
>
> So, what was the name of our erudite scholar? None other than Rav
>   Shlomo Zalman Auerbach zt”l, later to become the Gadol HaDor in his
>   own right! His letter actually turned out to be one of his most famous
>   published halachic rulings in his three volume collection of responsa,
>   Shu”t Minchas Shlomo.

In short, it seems that a cleaning of the dentures in hot water is fine, and even that may not be necessary.

Re denture cleaners, see [this](http://www.kashrut.com/Passover/pdf/YIBrookline_2014.pdf):

> Kosher for Pesach without " Pesach Hechsher " - Brimm’s Denturite
>   Liquid, Cushion Grip Denture Adhesive, Fixodent Cream,Fixodent Denture
>   Cleanser, Polident.

I'm unaware of other brands around that aren't listed. So, if you have one of these brands, not only don't you need to sell them, but you can use them during Pesach. Happy cleaning and Happy Pesach!

Comment: Ha, maybe. (I don't think his brand was one of the ones listed here, but I'll check)

Comment: @Shokhet Offhand, I think that all the denture cleaners are all chemicals and would be considered non-food, anyway. It's possible that even a brand not listed may be usable. You know what to do to find out, for sure :-)

Comment: You're right, it's probably completely inedible. And, to your second point, of course :)

Comment: @Shokhet I would suggest feeding it to a dog, and see if he eats it. But, according to a story I heard, someone asked Rav Moshe Soloveichick if toothpaste had to be Kosher Lepesach, and R. Moshe said no, b/c a dog wouldn't eat it. The student fed the toothpaste to his dog, which ate it. The student said to R. Moshe - "My dog did eat it so I really DO need buy KP toothpaste."  R. Moshe responded - "Your dog is an idiot!" So, even if your dog eats Polident, it wouldn't prove anything.

Comment: That's a great story. :)

Answer (score 1):

This was discussed as an aside in an article in this year's [YU Pesach To-Go (5777)](http://www.yutorah.org/togo/Pesach/), in an article titled "[Kosher for Passover Teeth!?](http://download.yutorah.org/2017/1053/Pesach_To-Go_-_5777_Rabbi_Schnall.pdf)" by Rabbi Eitan Schnall.

> #### Dentures on Pesach
>
> In light of the confluence of the many factors mentioned above, it is
> clear that natural teeth do not pose a kashrut concern on Pesach, and
> one merely has to clean his or her teeth well following chametz
> consumption on erev Pesach. Poskim apply the above principles in
> responsa regarding the use of dentures for milk and meat and on
> Pesach. The obvious difference is that dentures are removable and may
> undergo a more thorough *kashering* process, and perhaps must. In
> fact, *Shut Tzitz Eliezer* (9:25) records that the author of *Shut
> Tzemach Tzedek* had several sets of dentures manufactured for him by a
> dentist in Vienna, to distinguish between milk, meat and Pesach.
>
> On the opposite side of the spectrum, those of the opinion that teeth
> never absorb chametz because food in the mouth is never *yad soledet
> bo*, do not require any additional measures to prepare dentures for
> Pesach.<sup>17</sup> However, Rav Shlomo Zalman Auerbach insisted that
> chametz *bliyot* should be purged. He would *kasher* his dentures each
> Pesach, rather than rely on the various *tzdadim l’hakel* (mitigating
> factors) discussed above.
>
> <sup>17</sup> Chazon Ish quoted in *Orchot Rabbeinu* (2:27), *Igrot
> Moshe* (O.C. 1:5). See also *Tzitz Eliezer* (9:25) citing Rav Tzvi
> Pesach Frank. Rav Shmuel Fuerst reports that Rav Moshe Feinstein
> recommended refraining from consumption of hot chametz and *davar
> charif* within 24 hours of the start of Pesach.

The article made no mention of denture cleaners; as [DanF notes](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/81746/5323), a [2014 kashrut.com article](http://www.kashrut.com/Passover/pdf/YIBrookline_2014.pdf) lists several brands of Pesach-acceptable denture cleaners.

Answer (score 1):

The ingredients in denture cleaners would appear to be chemicals that would make the tablets kosher for passover. Apparently, kitniyos or chametz are not used.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denture_cleaner#Ingredients) shows the following ingredients:

> **Ingredients**
>
> Dilute sodium hypochlorite (i.e. a mild bleach) is the main
>   constituent of several brands of denture cleanser.
>
> Other ingredients include such chemicals as:
>
> - sodium bicarbonate - or baking soda, which alkalizes the water,    cleaning the dentures.
> - citric acid - removes stains.
> - sodium perborate
> - sodium polyphosphate
> - potassium monopersulfate - cleaning and bleaching agent
> - EDTA