# Medical dental supplies Kashrut for Passover considerations

Tags: passover, medicine, chametz-leaven

Should one be suspicious of any dental supplies for being *hametz* when one goes for a dental appointment during Passover?

Let's put rules of labor and scheduling-for-*hol hamoed* aside: I'm asking theoretically just about the dental treatment supplies.

Comment: What’s your concern? That the toothpaste etc. contains Chametz? That the dentist tools may have absorbed Chametz from someone else’s mouth? The former is נפסל לאכילת כלב and the latter is moot since everything is sterilized.

Comment: somewhat related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/81740/do-dentures-denture-cleaning-tablets-need-to-be-kosher-for-passover/81768#81768

Comment: I doubt there would be a concern regarding Chametz on dental tools. All tools are sterilized (they had better be!) in an extremely hot environment that it would probably be considered to *ha'agala*. Also, many dentists use disposable tools.

Comment: @DonielF Is there a prohibition against _benefiting_ from supplies which may include hamtez as an ingredient (eg. if the anithestic has hametz)?

Comment: @Yaakov If it’s נפסל לאכילת כלב it doesn’t count as food that the prohibition of chametz could apply.